# How to make datepicker show all dates of the month in one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I'm new to jQuery and I'm currently trying to figure out a way to manipulate datepicker so that it would show all the dates of a single month in just one row.

I'm trying to build a multi-unit hotel reservation-type calendar to be used as admin (not client-facing). I've got so far as to build a calendar-looking thing from scratch using loops and `<ul>` (this is from my research of popular BnB websites that have calendars with blocking click-and-drag functionalities). So the multi-unit calendar for February would have Days 1-28 as columns, and each unit/room as the rows.

I know jQuery comes with documentation for their API but in all honesty I have crawled through the interwebs and there is just not a single answer for my question.

Is there a simple method that controls how many cells printed per row? Because obviously a regular calendar always has 7 days per row. Or would I have to code this from scratch or is there somehow a more complicated but doable way with Datepicker?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: did you looked at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ it may save your lot of time for your project

Comment: not possible ith jquery-ui but you can show 7 days of the week in a row with all months of the year aligned in a row

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan Yes, actually I have seen it, I have scoured the depths of the internet. My question is more about how to take one of these plugins and manipulate the rows so that it doesn't print one row, print 7 days, print another row, another 7 days etc. but to print all 28 or 30 or 31 days in one row. Currently I'm working on a PHP solution but I like jQuery and want to learn how to work with it.

Comment: @YusafKhaliq Unfortunately that is not the point of my goal. I'm building a hotel unit reservations management calendar so each row would have to be a unit, and the columns would be the days of the month.

Comment: I am aware :) was just letting you know it's not possible with the jquery-ui datepicker, just to be clear what you are after is a datepicker with everyday of the month in a row and each month in a new row? BTW with this you wont be able to have a header of the day names i.e sun, mon, tues... unless you do it with every day which will look incredibly messy

Comment: Yes, every day of one month would be in one row, but each row would not be a new month. Each row would be a rental unit for a hotel/bnb. Here's a photo of the concept: http://hotelmanagementsoftware.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/hotelogix-45716.gif